# C# not able to get console Logs from PhantomJSDriver (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium in C# with the PhantomJS Driver.
I need to click specific coordinates on a website, that works with using Javascript (im using the ExecutePhantomJS(string script) function of the selenium phantomjs driver). I also need to capture the network traffic. I used browsermob earlier to do that, but for now i cant use it because i also need to use another proxy. So i solved it like that until now:

```
//Hide CMD of PhantomJS.exe
        var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        //Initialize Driver and execute Network Script to capture traffic
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);
        driver.ExecutePhantomJS(networkScript);         

        //Call URL 
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

This is the networkScript:

```
 string networkScript = "var page = this; page.onResourceRequested = function(req) { console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4)); }; page.onResourceReceived = function(res) { console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4)); };";
```

The good thing:
URL is called and all network traffic is logged into the console of the PhantomJS.exe.
But I dont know how I can get these console logs now in my C# code (I need to get specific things like URLs etc.. out of the network log).

I already read the whole afternoon but couldn't find a solution until now. Some of the things I already tried:

1) Tried to use PhantomJSOptions, there u can set LoggingPreferences and later i called driver.Manager().Logs.GetLog(LogType), but there were none of the console logs

2) Dont use console.log inside networkScript. I used require('system').stdout.write(...). It was also logged into console but I cant get the standard output stream of the phantomjs.exe from my C# code.

...

I really dont know how i could solve the problem.
One way would be to log into a .txt file instead of console, but it is very much text and later there will be many opened drivers, so I want to avoid that because then i will have very much and big .txt files